# Common among shapes

Tags: pattern, lateral-thinking, dissection

What is common to the following real, physical objects:

1. A cardboard/piece of paper carved as letter **E** (with all the segments of equal size)
2. A cardboard/ piece of paper shaped as two full cycles of a sinusoidal wave
3. A cardboard/piece of paper shaped as two full cycles of a square wave?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Based on this can you suggest another shape satisfying the above common property?

(Courtesy: Edward Bono's book on lateral thinking)

Hint 1:

> It is something to do with the latest tag added (and it is the biggest hint)

Hint 2:

> Ponder over the number and * * a * * of individual  *segments* of each of the given objects(when the act mentioned as the latest tag performed in a certain way on each of these objects)

Comment: ...They're all cardboard or pieces of paper? That's a property they have in common.

Comment: By "full cycles" you mean periods I guess? Any reason why this is posted "text only" ? Having figures would clarify it a lot unless "coming up with the picture" is part of the answer. Somehow, though, it seems that this needs a bit of refinement so that it's not going to be come a guess-what-I-am-thinking puzzle.

Comment: @BmyGuest yes I meant by full cycle a period. I try to attach images.

Comment: In the E you drew, the segments don’t seem to be of equal size. And the 2nd and 3rd “shapes” are just lines so how to cut out an area?

Comment: @Laska, good question. I did not draw letter E nor the waves. Those are for representation purpose only. You are in the right track - I mean if you proceed with cutting of **shapes** as described in the OP.

Answer (score 5):

> The letter E is actually a [Pulse wave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse_wave) so what's common to them is that they are all waves. Another shape can be a triangle wave.

[image]

> Turning the red "circle" cardboard of the image above 90 degrees to the right will create the letter E.(for people who don't understand how E can be pulse wave).

Comment: Good attempt, but in the link provided for pulse wave, nothing is mentioned about its similarity to _E_ (though visual conveys it partially). Away from actual/intended answer.

Comment: @MeaCulpaNay I added an image(don't know how to put it in spoiler or whether it's necessary or not) and an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

One Solution is

> A triangle wave is a non-sinusoidal waveform named for its triangular shape. It is a periodic, piecewise linear, continuous real function.

Another Solution is

> The sawtooth wave (or saw wave) is a kind of non-sinusoidal waveform. It is so named based on its resemblance to the teeth of a plain-toothed saw with a zero rake angle.

Picture
[image]